# Drupal Twig conversion... tpl.php to html.twig I don´t undertand a point in the tutorial

Tags: drupal, twig

I´m getting crazy with drupal... yesterday was my first day and I´m alone in this problem... I´m following this tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/node/2025313

Problem... I did everything and I guess that by the moment everything is ok. I´m reading, and reading... the 3 step, it say this:

```
Place your new Twig template in the templates folder in the stark theme (in the sandbox):
 for functions that came from specific module, stark/templates/comment, etc
 for functions that came from theme.inc, stark/templates/theme.inc
 for functions that came from form.inc, stark/templates/form.inc
```

I dont get anything... can some help me with this?

- What is the sandbox? My Drupal´s control panel?
- Functions that came from... WTF? I have a script with 1500 lines of code... (I´m not sure, but more than 1000, my html.twig...) I think this tutorial is for people with a lot experience in Drupal (I don´t have that experience) and maybe somethings like this could be easy or simple to people that works with drupal everythay...

I just need get what is the "stark theme", "the sandbox"...functions from there? ... I´m sure I dont´get something simple... =(

Thanks to everyone could help me.

Comment: Unfortunately those instructions are really out of date. All I can say for now is ignore anything talking about the sandbox, and probably ignore anything talking about the stark theme. Just stick to your own theme/module.